# Как прочесть массив значений из строки MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, массивы, база-данных

Добрый день. Есть строка в БД которая содержит числовые значения (массив).
Как прочесть этот массив и как его лучше писать в БД.

Подробнее: 
Есть список специалистов в БД которые оказывают несколько услуг. В БД у специалистов они(услуги) записаны в виде своих ID в одной строке как

```
a:3:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;i:2;i:30;}
```

Далее нужно вывести список специалистов и список оказываемых ими услуг в числовом виде. Использовал для чтения функцию

```
unserialize( $value['uslygi'] );
```

Мне кажется, что я запутался в синтаксисе кода, а возможно это можно сделать как то проще.

```
$query = " SELECT * FROM t_specialist " ; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error()); 
$myarray = array();

$n = mysql_num_rows($result);

for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)
{
    $myarray[] = mysql_fetch_array($result);
}

    foreach($myarray as $value){
    $array = unserialize( $value['uslygi'] );


    echo "<br>Специалист: ".$value['name']." Оказывает услуги: ". ТУТ НУЖНО ВЫВЕСТИ ID ОКАЗЫВАЕМЫХ УСЛУГ;


    }



?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на вопрос как перевести массив в строку - функция [implode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php)

```
echo implode(',', $array);
```

Comment: Здорово! Спасибо. Только как теперь заменить каждое значение именем услуги из таблицы (t_uslygi)? Т.е. мне нужна не просто строка а ID каждой услуги для последующей работы с БД.

Answer (score 1):

Подобная сериализация обьекта языка программирования в **реляционную базу данных** в вашей задаче является **причиной многих проблем и ошибок**. Правильная запись в базу подобных значений должна сопровождаться отдельной таблицей и связью один ко многим. Обязательно создайте поле id в t_specialist, если его нет!

Удалите из таблицы t_specialist поле uslugi, и создайте новую таблицу t_specialist_services, которая будет содержать следующую структуру:

- specialist_id INT
- service_id TINYINT unsigned (я не думаю, что услуг будет больше 256)

Заполните ее. После чего делайте запрос с применением JOIN

```
SELECT ts.id, GROUP_CONCAT(service_id) services_id FROM t_specialist ts JOIN t_specialist_services tss ON ts.id = tss.specialist_id GROUP BY tss.id
```

Или

```
SELECT ts.id, service_id FROM t_specialist ts JOIN t_specialist_services tss ON ts.id = tss.specialist_id
```

В первом случае, в каждой строке вы получите specialist_id и список услуг через запятую в поле services_id, а в последнем случае вы получаете множественные записи в виде номера специалиста и номер услуги, но вы можете данные сгурпировать их на своей стороне и удобно использовать. Например, вот так:

```
$services = [];

//$data данные из mysql
foreach ($data as $item) {
   $services[$item->id][] = $item->service_id;
}
```

P.S **Прекратите использовать мамонта в виде расширения MYSQL**, пора переходить на новое! В лучшем случае PDO или Mysqli

Comment: Огромное спасибо за развёрнутый ответ, буду вникать, а что касаемо PDO или Mysqli посоветуй те статью для осознания. Ещё раз благодарю.

Comment: http://phpfaq.ru/pdo - статья про PDO, но в целом вы можете любую по своему вкусу найти в поисковике. Почитайте про нормальные формы в БД https://habrahabr.ru/post/254773/, это также Вам пригодится. Правильная архитектура - залог экономии времени в будущем при ее поддержании.